# OWASP Top 10 updates

Tags: owasp

Has the OWASP top 10 project not been updated since 2010?

Having had a look at the following site on OWASP I can see that this may be the case: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project

My company is making a big deal out of OWASP compliance, so I just want to be sure that I'm up to date?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update -- OWASP Top Ten 2017 was released.  You can always find the latest version here. https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project

> OWASP Top Ten 2013 was released today!  You can download here http://owasptop10.googlecode.com/files/OWASP%20Top%2010%20-%202013%20-%20RC1.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the [2010](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2010) version of the OWASP Top Ten is the latest version. Before that, the last version was in [2007](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007). If more people volunteered, it would get updated more often, but most of us who work on OWASP projects also hold down full-time day jobs, so progress can be frustratingly slow at times.

Comment: There is not a 2013 version of the OWASP Top Ten out. (Figures I'd let you all know in 2014, right? :) It is available at: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10

Comment: Kevin did you mean there is *now* a 2013 version out?

Comment: Yes, I mean the 2013 version is out _now_. I think it was announced at AppSec USA 2013 in NYC back in November.

Comment: (Or rather, I _meant_.) Anyhow, you should definitely take a look at it, because there are some new issues that weren't in the top 10 in the 2010 version. The one I recall that is new is "A9  Using Components with Known Vulnerabilities". There was a talk on that at AppSec USA.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK - there is a 2013 update in progress.

Contact Dave Wichers for more info, or better yet, volunteer on the topten mail list. :)